# How to create mysql stored procedures with laravel eloquent?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I want to create stored procedures to improve performance of my application that build with Laravel so I want to use Eloquent to create it. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If your procedure doesn't have any parameter, you can call it by :

`DB::select('EXEC myProcedure')`

With parameters, it looks like :

`DB::select('EXEC myProcedure("myParam1", "myParam2")');`

or

`DB::select('EXEC myProcedure(?,?)', array($param1, $param2));`